# Xcode isn't showing anything in console only on first run

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Ok, this is very a weird thing.

When I run my App in the Simulator or the Device for the first time, Xcode doesn't put anything in the console.

If I stop the app, and run it again, then it all works as expected.

This only happens if I have the app uninstalled.

I'm using Xcode 4.2 in OSX Lion.

Do the same happen to you?

Answer (score 0):

Yep... afaik it has always been like that. Also true for first run on a real device.